# Highcharts add series dynamically

Tags: json, charts, highcharts

I want to add some series (I get the series data from a webservice as a 3dim array (and returning it as json) - I dont know the number of series I will get, so I have to load the series data dynamically).

In javascript I am building an object: (like this highstock example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/)

```
seriesOptions[i] = {
    name: namearray[i],
    data: dataarray
};

e.g. result: [Object { name="Series", data=[[1041375600000, 29,9]]}]
```

I was trying to add the series like this:

```
$.each(seriesOptions, function (itemNo, item) {
    chart.addSeries({                        
        name: item.name,
        data: item.data
    }, false);
});
chart.redraw();
```

But the chart draws the series kinda weird and doesnt convert to timestamp to date.
Are there any problems with my chart data from the webservice?

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/DGdaf/2/

Thanks for any help so far.

**EDIT**
It seems like the chart ignoeres all the default values of timeline/zoom value.
I have no idea why it doesnt display these components.
The problem could be, that I am drawing the chart after the initialization?

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

But I have to do it cause of the dynamic series loading.

**EDIT2**
I am not sure if I am loading too much data or something. I cant create my series dynamically.

```
for(i=0; i<seriesOptions.length; i++){
        chart.addSeries({                        
            name: seriesOptions[i].name,
            data: seriesOptions[i].data
        }, true);

    };
```

Comment: Could you add to your jsFiddle sample data?

Comment: sample data of the 3dim array and the js object: http://jsfiddle.net/eAu32/

Answer (score 5):

Set for your yAxis:

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGdaf/4/)

EDIT: 
Timeline / zoom
http://jsfiddle.net/DGdaf/5/

Edit: 
Use callback to add series, when chart is ready. However, why don't you add these series when chart is created?

```
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options, function(ch) {

        $.each(seriesOptions, function (itemNo, item) {
            ch.addSeries({                        
                name: item.name,
                data: item.data
            }, false);

        });
        chart.redraw();
    });
```

Comment: its looking weird from here: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/2685/7y5l.jpg  I know - that I am useing more data than you, but idk why my chart draws points an the line

Comment: and there is no timeline/zoom value as well

Comment: Which timeline/zoom? Why do you think this is rendered in a wrong way?

Comment: Maybe you want Highstock chart - in that case ... see edit by Sebastian :)

Comment: The problem is: I want to add the series dynamically (see my edit at my post). - That means the number of series depends on the returned data of the webservice. I want to add my data with a for/foreach.

Comment: And what is the problem with adding that series..? Your screenshot add series. Se updated answer.

Comment: New info - Series cant be empty? see http://jsfiddle.net/DGdaf/8/ line 71-75. So i have to set series? and cant load them totally dynamic (line 93-100)?

Comment: thanks for your support so far - but when I am using the callback function, I am just getting an empty chart. (no data is displayed). http://jsfiddle.net/DGdaf/9/